# formulário não acessa a rota criada no laravel

Tags: php, formulário, laravel-rotas, laravel-5.2

tenho um formulário pronto que estou tentando incorporar a um sistema laravel 5.2

```
<form name="formEireli" id="formEireli" action="{{ url('script') }}"  target="_blank" method="post">
```

está na view eireli/index.blade.php, e o eireli/script.php eu tento acessar pela a rota:

```
Route::get('eireli.script', ['uses'=>'EireliController@eireli','as'=>'script']);
```

que acessa a função eireli do controller EireliController

```
class EireliController extends Controller
{
    public function eireli()
    {
        return view('eireli.script');
    }
}
```

mas não está dando certo, e não estou conseguindo entender o erro que aparece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguma luz pessoal? obrigado desde já..

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver com isso:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565479/notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-161-in-laravel-5

basicamente eu usei uma rota implícita, e criei os métodos no controller para tratar as requisições.